# Node on a jointed TikZ path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
  \path[draw,thick] (0,0) |- (1.5,1.5);
  \node at (0.75,1.5) [above] {Hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: Right-angled path shown with the word "Hi" mid-way along top branch]

In my mind, I can achieve the same effect by doing this:

```
\path[draw,thick] (0,0) |- node{Hi} (1.5,1.5);
```

But, when I try, I get:

[image: Right-angled path shown with the word "Hi" at the corner]

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

In

```
\path[draw,thick] (0,0) |- node{Hi} (1.5,1.5);
```

the node is placed at the middle of the path (`midway`, `pos=.5`).
The `|-` and `-|` operators are special because their middle lies exactly on the sharp kink.

The middle of second part of your path is therefore at `.75` of your whole path, thus

```
node[pos=.75,above]
```

is needed.

#### Example

```
  \path[draw] (0,0) -| (5,-1);
  \foreach \x in {0.0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0}{
    \path[draw] (0,0) -| node[pos=\x] {\x} (5,-1);
  }
```

#### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
  \path[draw,thick] (0,0) |- node[pos=.75,above] {Hi} (1.5,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### A different approach

As [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit) has mentioned in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/node-on-a-jointed-tikz-path/97404#comment209546_97404) there is also the possibility to avoid the specialties of `|-` and `-|` and actually use two path parts with the coordinate specification `|-` and `-|` (which are in fact only short-cuts for the perpendicular coordinate system).

In a path like

```
\path (<c1>) -- (<c1> |- <c2>) -- node {} (<c2>);
```

you do have two path parts:

- one from `<c1>` to the coordinate vertically through `<c1>` and horizontally through `<c2>`, and
- one from that point to `<c2>` where we want to place the node (at the middle of that part, see above).

If you want to use these two-parters repeatedly, I advise you to use custom `to path`s so that you do not need to repeat both coordinates. (The number stands for the path part where the node shall be placed at.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
 |- 1/.style={to path={-- (\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget) \tikztonodes -- (\tikztotarget)}},
 |- 2/.style={to path={-- (\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
 -| 1/.style={to path={-- (\tikztostart -| \tikztotarget) \tikztonodes -- (\tikztotarget)}},
 -| 2/.style={to path={-- (\tikztostart -| \tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw, thick]
\draw (0,0) to[|- 2] node{Hi} (1.5,1.5);
\draw (0,-1) to[-| 1] node{Hi} ++ (1.5,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Another possibility: `\path[draw,thick] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- 1.5,1.5) -- node{Hi} (1.5,1.5);`

Comment: @PaulGaborit Of course! I have added your possibility to my answer (while bringing in my own thoughts on the subject).