# Is It Possible to Combine TikZ Distance and Line-To Operations?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using LaTeX and TikZ, is it possible to use a Line-To operation in the same command as a distance operation? I would like to draw a rectangle and then create a named node at the midpoint of the upper edge of the rectangle. To do this I am using a Distance Operation to find the center of the Rectangle and then a Line-To Operation to find the upper edge. See below for the MWE code that I think should work, but is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (10,10) {};
\node [above right] at (A) {A};
\node [below left] at (B) {B};
\draw [draw=black] (B) rectangle (A);
\node at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$ |- B) {Top of Rect [incorrect]};
\node (ABMid) [below] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {Midpoint AB};
\node (rectTop) [above] at (ABMid|-B) {Top of Rect [correct]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not use such mathematical calculation to get a coordinate at the middle of the top line. Nodes on path can be placed quite intelligently.

The problem here is that the node placement on the original `rectangle` path is only on a straight line between the two coordinates, so the nodes on the two following paths are on the same place with the same `<pos>`:

```
\path (c1) --        node[pos=<pos>] {} (c2);
\path (c1) rectangle node[pos=<pos>] {} (c2);
```

I’ll have three solutions for you.

1. A simply auxiliary coordinate.
2. Replacing the `rectangle` path with two `|-`/`-|` paths.
3. Using a proper *timer* functions for the `rectangle` path via the `ext.paths.timer` from my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).

### Solution 1

With an auxiliary coordinate you can simply do

```
\draw (B) rectangle coordinate (aux1) (A) node[above] at (aux1 |- B) {Top of the Rect};
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=above right:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below left:B] (B) at (20,10);
\draw (B) rectangle coordinate (aux1) (A) node[above] at (aux1 |- B) {Top of the Rect};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Solution 2

Use two combined `|-` or `-|` and the position `.75` or `.25` (respectively). The corners have the position `.5` (→ [Node on a jointed TikZ path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97399/16595)).

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=above right:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below left:B] (B) at (20,10);
\draw (B) -| node[pos=.25, above] {Top of the Rect} (A) -| (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Solution 3

Load the `ext.paths.timer` library then you can use `very near start` (`pos = 0.125`) to access the middle of the first (top) side.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.timer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=above right:A] (A) at ( 0, 0);
\coordinate [label=below  left:B] (B) at (20,10);
\draw (B) rectangle node[very near start, above] {Top of the Rect} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I refrained from using the `pos` command as a rectangle is not necessarily a square, in which case it will be _difficult_ (well, to a certain extent) to find the top point.

Comment: @zeroth The middle of the top line lies always at `0.125` (solution A) or `1.875` (updated solution B). I have also changed the coordinate of `B` to `(20,0)` to highlight this. Of course, if you want a node at a specific distance on the line (and not a ratio of the path’s length), one should either use directly `([xshift=-<distance>] B)`, a timer function that calculates the position from a distance or the `markings` library with `mark=at position <distance> with \node {…}`.

Comment: Great! I had completely forgotten about the `pos=.5 == corner` thingy! That was what was troubling me! Great! Thanks! :) Maybe if you elaborate on this in the post it will be more clear (as it generally is a non expected feature). I mean quarter way on a path is actually half-way on the first line segment when dealing with line-to operations!

Comment: I will probably use the first solution with a slight modification:   `\draw[red, thick, rounded corners=3pt] (A) -| (B) coordinate[pos=0.25] (test) -| (A);`

Comment: @zeroth See my update. Maybe `\draw (B) rectangle coordinate (aux1) (A) node[above] at (aux1 |- B) {Top of the Rect};` (see my first solution)  is the easiest. Though, I do not like solutions where I have to specify one coordinate twice.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: An inline calculation is seen in the bottom.

In principle it is. I haven't really optimized the below, it could be reduced somewhat.

You can utilize the `let` operator (which also comes from the `calc` library).

What you want to do is obtain the maximum *y* coordinate and then select the half *x* coordinate. So you need the *x* and *y* coordinates of each point.

Furthermore you should *never* specify a coordinate using a `node`! This can give very unforseen problems. Remember that nodes retain a size, whereas coordinates does not.

I would do your system something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \node[above right] at (A) {A};
  \coordinate (B) at (10,10);
  \node[below left] at (B) {B};
  \draw [draw=black] (A) rectangle (B);
  \draw let \p1 = (A),
          \p2 = (B),
          \n{x} = {(\x1+\x2)/2},
          \n{y} = {max(\y1,\y2)} in
          (\n{x},\n{y}) node[above] {Top of Rect [incorrect]};
  \coordinate (ABMid) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \node at (ABMid) {Midpoint AB};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Of course, if you don't need the coordinate `ABMid` then just do `\node at ($(A)!.5!(B)$) {...};`

What the above does is calculating *on the path* the *x* and *y* coordinate of your top point. `\p<int> = (<coordinate>)` will save *x* and *y* in `\x<int>,\y<int>` for further computation within the `let` line. The `\n{x}` line calculates the *x*-coordinate of your top point, and the `\n{y}` line calculates the maximum *y*-coordinate.

The above will yield:

[image]

I realized that you really wanted something inline (which is doable but *ugly*).
So what you can do is project `B` onto the vertical line starting in `A`, then calculate the middle point between this and `B`, that will give you the half way on the line you need.

So this can be done via this *obscure* construct:

```
\coordinate (ABMidTop) at ($(A)!(B)!($(A)+(0,1)$)!.5!(B)$); 
\node[above] at (ABMidTop) {Top of Rect [incorrect]};
```

It should be read like this:
draw the line `A` to `A+(0,1)`, then project `B` onto this line. Then take the halfway point between the previous calculated point and `B`.