# TikZ reusable paths with variables

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a rectangle path and annotating node that I can parameterize with coordinates, style, and text.  Currently, I'm doing this:

```
\draw[styA] (\Axi,\Ayi) -- (\Axi,\Ayi + \Ayii) node[midway, right] {annotation A} -- (\Axi + \Axii,\Ay + \Ayii) -- (\Axi + \Axii,\Ayi) -- cycle;
\draw[styB] (\Bxi,\Byi) -- (\Bxi,\Byi + \Byii) node[midway, right] {annotation B} -- (\Bxi + \Bxii,\By + \Byii) -- (\Bxi + \Bxii,\Byi) -- cycle;
\draw[styC] (\Cxi,\Cyi) -- (\Cxi,\Cyi + \Cyii) node[midway, right] {annotation C} -- (\Cxi + \Cxii,\Cy + \Cyii) -- (\Cxi + \Cxii,\Cyi) -- cycle;
...
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
\foreach \sty,\annotation,\xi,\xii,\yi,\yii (<more foreachy stuff>)
  \draw[\sty] (\xi,\yi) -- (\xi,\yi + \yii) node[midway, right] {\annotation} -- (\xi + \xii,\y + \yii) -- (\xi + \xii,\yi) -- cycle;
```

Or this:

```
\MyFancyCommand{\styA,\annotationA,\Axi,\Axii,\Ayi,\Ayii}
\MyFancyCommand{\styB,\annotationB,\Bxi,\Bxii,\Byi,\Byii}
\MyFancyCommand{\styC,\annotationC,\Cxi,\Cxii,\Cyi,\Cyii}
...
```

Is there a way to do something like one of these, or part of one of these without having to use an external preprocessor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a slightly different syntax, you can do this:

```
\foreach \sty/\annotation/\xi/\xii/\yi/\yii in {%
  <sty 1>/<annotation 1>/<xi 1>/<xii 1>/<yi 1>/<yii 1>,
  <sty 2>/<annotation 2>/<xi 2>/<xii 2>/<yi 2>/<yii 2>,
  …,
  <sty n>/<annotation n>/<xi n>/<xii n>/<yi n>/<yii n>}
  \draw[style/.expand once=\sty]
        (\xi, \yi)               -- (\xi, \yi + \yii) node[midway, right] {\annotation}
     -- (\xi + \xii, \yi + \yii) -- (\xi + \xii,  \yi) -- cycle;
```

It also might be useful to use relative coordinates:

```
  \draw[style/.expand once=\sty]
          (\xi,  \yi)  -- + (up:\yii) node[midway, right] {\annotation}
     -- + (\xii, \yii) -- + (right:\xi) -- cycle;
```

or even

```
 \draw[style/.expand once=\sty]
   (\xi,  \yi) |- + (\xii, \yii) node[near start, right] {\annotation} |- + (0, 0) -- cycle;
```

---

The code below shows an example and the same example with the a `to path` and the `to path` example with a `.list`ed key.

This allows also other coordinate systems than the cartesian one for both corners of the rectangles. (With the `edges` on one path, you can also specify the first corner of the rectangle as a relative coordinate to another rectangle.)

There is also the `rectangle` path operator, i.e `(corner A) rectangle (corner B)`, but unfortunately, there is no proper timer setup to place the nodes, see [Is It Possible to Combine TikZ Distance and Line-To Operations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106558/16595)

You might as well consider doing this as a node, see [tikz: Can we set the corner coordinates of a rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87989/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \sty/\annotation/\xi/\xii/\yi/\yii in {%
  draw                       /Foo/  0  /1/0  /2  ,
  {fill=blue!25, draw=blue}  /Bar/  1.5/2/-.5/1.5,
  {transform shape,rotate=30}/Woah!/2  /2/0.5/1  }
 \draw[style/.expand once=\sty]
  (\xi,  \yi) |- + (\xii, \yii) node[near start, right] {\annotation}
              |- + (0, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  my Rect/.style={
    to path={
      |- node[near start, right] {#1} (\tikztotarget) |- (\tikztostart)}}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,     0) edge[my Rect=Foo]                               + (1,2)
      (1.5, -.5) edge[my Rect=Bar, fill=blue!25, draw=blue]      + (2, 1.5)
      (2,   0.5) edge[my Rect=Woah!, rotate=30, transform shape] + (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my Foreach/.style args={[#1]#2:#3)#4}{
  insert path={#3) edge[my Rect={#2},#1] #4}}]
\path [my Foreach/.list={{[]                           Foo:  (0,0)     +(1,2)  },
                         {[fill=blue!25, draw=blue]    Bar:  (1.5,-.5) +(2,1.5)},
                         {[rotate=30, transform shape] Woah!:(2,0.5)   +(2,1)  }}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an excellent with much great information. This exchange, though, has caused me to realize that I can't simplify what I'm already doing without complicating it in another way

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (\SixteenEightyfive,1) -- (\SixteenEightyfive,2) node[midway,right] {Bach} -- (\SeventeenFifty,2) -- (\SeventeenFifty,1) -- cycle;
    \draw (\NinteenTwentysix,1) -- (\NinteenTwentysix,2) node[midway,right] {Coltrane} -- (\NinteenSixtyseven,2) -- (\NinteenSixtyseven,1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

because the time scale is logarithmic. I guess I should have been more specific.