# TikZ: How to place a coordinate at parabola-path-position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I want to have a coordinate like `coordinate[pos=0.675](X)`
It seems not to works. What have I to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[marigin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[] (0,0) -- (3,5) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=N](N) node{works};  
\draw[blue] (0,0) arc (0:75:4) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=A](A) node{works too};  
\draw[red, shift={(2,0)}](0,0) parabola [parabola height =3cm](4,0) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=P] (P) node{works not}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your observation is correct. Second, this is by far not the only path construction that does not have a "timer". For instance, this is also true for the `sin` and `cos` path constructions, and of course plots.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[] (0,0) -- (3,5) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=N](N)
 node[circle,draw]{\ding{51}};  
\draw[blue] (0,0) arc (0:75:4) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=A](A) node[circle,draw]{\ding{51}};  
\draw[red, shift={(2,0)}](0,0) parabola [parabola height =3cm](4,0) 
coordinate[pos=0.675, label=P] (P) node[circle,draw]{\ding{55}}; 
\draw[cyan, shift={(6,2)}](0,0) sin(2,1)  
coordinate[pos=0.675, label=Q] (Q) node[circle,draw]{\ding{55}}; 
\draw[cyan, shift={(6,4.5)}](0,0) cos(2,-1)  
coordinate[pos=0.675, label=R] (R) node[circle,draw]{\ding{55}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, the `pos` syntax only really works for

1. straight lines (`\tikz@timer@line`),
2. single Bezier curve stretches (`\tikz@timer@curve`), and
3. arcs (`\tikz@timer@arc`).

So what is going on here? Internally Ti*k*Z works with a "timer", the relevant macros from `tikz.code.tex` are `\tikz@timer` (as well as `\tikz@timer@start` and `\tikz@timer@end`). As far as I can see, only `\tikz@timer@line` (with the subcases `\tikz@timer@hvline` and `\tikz@timer@vhline`), `\tikz@timer@curve` and `\tikz@timer@arc` are implemented. If your question is whether or not one could add a timer for parabolae, sines and cosines, the answer is likely affirmative, but given the complexity of the other timers in `tikz.code.tex` the actual realization will be messy.

So, in order to answer the question

> How to place a coordinate at parabola-path-position?

I recommend looking at the `decorations.markings` library.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,postaction={decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.675 with {\coordinate[label=P](P);}}}]
(0,0) parabola [parabola height =3cm](4,0)  node[below]{works}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(If you encounter `dimension too large errors` with this decoration, some of them can be cured with `use fpu reciprocal` that ships with `circuitikz`.)

As a side remark, if you use `pgfplots` the `pos` key does work for one-dimensional plots, even for pretty complex ones.

Answer (score 5):

As the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543268/16595) explains, for `parabola` no timer is set up, not even the line-to timer (as for [the `rectangle` path operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106558/16595)).

#### Patching `\tikz@parabola@semifanal`

However, we can hack one in by patching `\tikz@parabola@semifinal`. That's the TikZ macro that finalizes the `parabola` operator. *This however also breaks forwards compatibility.* The lines commented with `% %% Timer` are the ones I added. These are needed

- to save the start (`\edef\tikz@timer@start{…}`),
- to save the “bend” (`\xdef\tikz@timer@middle{…}`) and
- to save the end of the parabola (`\edef\tikz@timer@end`) as well as
- to actually instruct TikZ to use our custom timer (`\let\tikz@timer\tikz@timer@parabola`) which I piggy-back in `\tikz@parabola@b` to not have to deal with the `\expandafter`s.

#### New timer for parabolas

The new timer `\tikz@timer@parabola` uses these tree saved points (we might be able to use `\tikz@parabola@b` again but then we also had to do all these calculations again).

The timer is set up in a way that the bend is always at `pos = 0.5`, this means however that when we draw only one side of the parabola, half the points collapse into the bend (see the second example).

Since PGF's parabolas are actually drawn as arcs we can use `\pgftransformcurveattime`, the control points are calculated the same as they are for drawing the parabolas.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@parabola@semifinal#1{%
    \tikz@flush@moveto%
    % Save original start:
    \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}% %% Timer: save start position
    \pgf@xb=\tikz@lastx%
    \pgf@yb=\tikz@lasty%
    \tikz@make@last@position{#1}%
    \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}% %% Timer: save target position
    \pgf@xc=\tikz@lastx%
    \pgf@yc=\tikz@lasty%
    \begingroup% now calculate bend:
        \let\tikz@after@path\pgfutil@empty%
        \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\tikz@parabola@option}%
        \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@parabola@bend@factor\tikz@lastx%
        \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@parabola@bend@factor\tikz@lasty%
        \advance\tikz@lastxsaved by\pgf@xb%
        \advance\tikz@lastysaved by\pgf@yb%
        \advance\tikz@lastxsaved by-\tikz@parabola@bend@factor\pgf@xb%
        \advance\tikz@lastysaved by-\tikz@parabola@bend@factor\pgf@yb%
        \expandafter\tikz@make@last@position\expandafter{\tikz@parabola@bend}%
        \xdef\tikz@timer@middle{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}% %% Timer: save bend postion
        % Calculate delta from bend
        \advance\pgf@xc by-\tikz@lastx%
        \advance\pgf@yc by-\tikz@lasty%
        % Ok, now calculate delta to bend
        \advance\tikz@lastx by-\pgf@xb%
        \advance\tikz@lasty by-\pgf@yb%
        \xdef\tikz@parabola@b{{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}}%
            \noexpand\let\noexpand\tikz@timer\noexpand\tikz@timer@parabola}% %% Timer added
    \expandafter\endgroup%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfpathparabola\expandafter\tikz@parabola@b%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\tikz@after@path%
}%
\def\tikz@timer@parabola{% following calculations, see \def of \pgfpathparabola in pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex (l. 1261)
    \ifdim\tikz@time pt<.5pt\relax % first part
        \pgf@process{\tikz@timer@middle}%
        \pgf@xc\pgf@x\pgf@yc\pgf@y
        \pgf@xb\pgf@x\pgf@yb\pgf@y
        \pgf@process{\tikz@timer@start}%
        \advance\pgf@xc-\pgf@x\pgf@xc.1125\pgf@xc
        \advance\pgf@xc\pgf@x                 % = start_x + .1125 (middle_x - start_x)
        \advance\pgf@yc-\pgf@y\pgf@yc.225\pgf@yc
        \advance\pgf@yc\pgf@y                 % = start_y + .225 (middle_y - start_y)
        \advance\pgf@xb\pgf@x\pgf@xb.5\pgf@xb % = .5 (middle_x + start_x) = start_x + .5 (middle_x - start_x)
        \pgf@xa=\tikz@time pt%
        \pgf@xa=2\pgf@xa                      % = 2 * \tikz@time
        \edef\tikz@marshall{\noexpand\pgftransformcurveattime{\strip@pt\pgf@xa}{\noexpand\tikz@timer@start}%
                           {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}}%
                           {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xb}{\the\pgf@yb}}%
                           {\noexpand\tikz@timer@middle}}%
        \tikz@marshall
    \else % second part
        \pgf@process{\tikz@timer@end}%
        \pgf@xc\pgf@x
        \pgf@xb\pgf@x
        \pgf@yb\pgf@y
        \pgf@process{\tikz@timer@middle}%
        \advance\pgf@xc\pgf@x\pgf@xc.5\pgf@xc % = .5 (end_x + middle_x) = middle_x + .5 (end_x - middle_x)
        \advance\pgf@xb-\pgf@x\pgf@xb.8875\pgf@xb
        \advance\pgf@xb\pgf@x                 % = middle_x + .8875 (end_x - middle_x)
        \advance\pgf@yb-\pgf@y\pgf@yb.775\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@yb\pgf@y                 % = middle_y + .775 (end_y - middle_y)
        \pgf@xa=\tikz@time pt%
        \advance\pgf@xa-.5pt%
        \pgf@xa=2\pgf@xa                      % = 2 (\tikz@zime - .5)
        \edef\tikz@marshall{\noexpand\pgftransformcurveattime{\strip@pt\pgf@xa}{\noexpand\tikz@timer@middle}%
                           {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@y}}%
                           {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xb}{\the\pgf@yb}}%
                           {\noexpand\tikz@timer@end}}%
        \tikz@marshall
    \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[]     (0,0) --  (3,5)    coordinate[pos=0.675, label=N] (N) node {works};  
    \draw[blue] (0,0) arc (0:75:4) coordinate[pos=0.675, label=A] (A) node {works too};  
    \draw[red, shift={(2,0)}](0,0) parabola [parabola height =3cm] (4,0)
                                   coordinate[pos=0.4,   label=P] (P) node {works now}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines]  (-2.25,-1.25) grid (2.25,3.25);
    \draw              ( 2,-1) parabola bend (0,0) (-1,3);
    \draw[ultra thick] (-2,-1) parabola bend (0,0) ( 1,3) foreach \pos in {1,...,4,6,7,...,9}
                               {node[pos=\pos/10,sloped,fill=white,font=\tiny,inner sep=+0pt]{\pos}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, overlay] (-3,-3) grid (1.25, 1);
    \draw                      (-2,-2) parabola (1,0)
         foreach \pos in {0,1,...,10} {node[pos=\pos/10, alias=@, inner sep=+1pt,
            append after command={(@) edge node[pos=1,font=\tiny,inner sep=+0pt,anchor=-18*\pos+90]
               {\pos} ++(-18*\pos+270:.5cm) }] {.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: two different parabolas]
[image: half a parabola]