# draw the connect line using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw the picture as following:
[image]

I write the code to draw the picture, however, I don't know how to draw the line that connects the diamond to the circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 2em, minimum height=1em},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm]
\node[my box,align=center](s1){$S_1$};
\node[draw,circle,left = of s1](start){};
\draw[->] (start)--(s1);
\node[draw,diamond,right = of s1](end){};
\draw[->] (s1)--(end);
\end{tikzpicture
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is similar to [How to draw a return arrow from node-3 to node-1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385) Do you still need help with that? (By the way, could you complete your MWE so that it has proper libraries loaded and an existing `document` environment?)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks, I have draw the line, however, I don;t know how to adjust the location of "k"?

Comment: @sweetyBaby I’d use `\draw[->] (end) -- ++(0,.5cm) -| (start) node[pos=.25,above] {$k$};` and the `k` sits right in the middle of the top line. See also [Node on a jointed TikZ path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97399) for node placement on `|-`/`-|` paths.