# Connecting from in the middle of |- line

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      % type of arrow head
      >=stealth',
      % keep arrow head from touching the surface
      shorten >= 1pt,
      % automatic node positioning
      auto,
      % 
      node distance=1.2cm,
      % line thickness
      semithick,
      graybox/.style = {draw=gray!20, fill=gray!20, rounded corners},
      line/.style = {draw=black, thick},
      team/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm}
    ]

    \coordinate (O) at (0cm, 0cm);

    % this node is named 'C1' and located at (O). Its style is 'team'
    \node [team] (C1) at (O) {\small 1};
    \node [team] (C2) [below of=C1] {\small 2};
    \node [team] (C3) [below of=C2] {\small 3};
    \node [team] (C4) [below of=C3] {\small 4};
    \node [team] (C5) [below of=C4] {\small 5};

    \path [line] (C5) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- (C4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is a LaTeX code that I wrote to generate a simple diagram.

[image]

But what I really want is something like this.

```
1 --------------+
                |
                |
2 ----------+   |
            |   |
            |   |
3 ------+   +---+
        |   |
        +---+
4 --+   |
    |   |
    +---+
    |
5 --+
```

I can connect 4 and 5 using `|-` command, but I don't know how to label in the middle of this vertical line and then connect it to `3`.
What is the best way to draw the above ASCII art in LaTeX?

Comment: I think this is a perfect use case for the `udlr` library of our @Qrrbrbirlbel that can be found in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/how-to-draw-a-return-arrow-from-node-3-to-node-1 But I didn't use it and he warns about the incompatibility possibilities.

In the meantime you can use the `calc` computation.

Comment: @percusse Indeed, the code in the answer you linked to is quite outdated (most likely my first version of the concept of udlr connections). I even found a bug where the connection between node and coordinate (and vice versa) fails.

Comment: Be careful with `(node) ++(1cm,0cm)` as it calculates the difference to the `.center` of `node` (which might just be inside the node itself), it also makes the first connection closer to the nodes as the other connections are to the previous connection.

Comment: Related: [Node on a jointed TikZ path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97399/16595)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The starting points on the line can be calculated. The following example takes the middle of the vertical line segment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      % type of arrow head
      >=stealth',
      % keep arrow head from touching the surface
      shorten >= 1pt,
      % automatic node positioning
      auto,
      % 
      node distance=1.2cm,
      % line thickness
      semithick,
      graybox/.style = {draw=gray!20, fill=gray!20, rounded corners},
      line/.style = {draw=black, thick},
      team/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm}
    ]

    \coordinate (O) at (0cm, 0cm);

    % this node is named 'C1' and located at (O). Its style is 'team'
    \node [team] (C1) at (O) {\small 1};
    \node [team] (C2) [below of=C1] {\small 2};
    \node [team] (C3) [below of=C2] {\small 3};
    \node [team] (C4) [below of=C3] {\small 4};
    \node [team] (C5) [below of=C4] {\small 5};

    \path [line] (C5) --++ (1cm, 0cm) coordinate (C45r) |- (C4);
    \path [line] ($(C5)!.5!(C4)$) coordinate (C45m)
                 (C45r |- C45m) --++ (1cm, 0cm) coordinate (C34r) |- (C3);
    \path [line] ($(C45m)!.5!(C3)$) coordinate (C34m)
                 (C34r |- C34m) --++ (1cm, 0cm) coordinate (C23r) |- (C2);
    \path [line] ($(C34m)!.5!(C2)$) coordinate (C23m)
                 (C23r |- C23m) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- (C1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

Here is a solution using `coordinate` and the `pos` option:

> Another interesting case are the horizontal/vertical line-to operations |- and -|. For them, the position (or time) 0.5 is exactly the corner point.
>
> <sub>*(from pgfmanual, p. 236, section 17.8 Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly)*</sub>

After `|-`, with position `0.25`, you get the middle of the vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % type of arrow head
  >=stealth',
  % keep arrow head from touching the surface
  shorten >= 1pt,
  % automatic node positioning
  auto,
  % 
  node distance=1.2cm,
  % line thickness
  semithick,
  graybox/.style = {draw=gray!20, fill=gray!20, rounded corners},
  line/.style = {draw=black, thick},
  team/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm}
  ]
  
  \coordinate (O) at (0cm, 0cm);
  % this node is named 'C1' and located at (O). Its style is 'team'
  \node [team] (C1) at (O) {\small 1};
  \node [team] (C2) [below of=C1] {\small 2};
  \node [team] (C3) [below of=C2] {\small 3};
  \node [team] (C4) [below of=C3] {\small 4};
  \node [team] (C5) [below of=C4] {\small 5};
  \path [line]    (C5) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- coordinate[pos=.25] (r-4-5) (C4);
  \path [line] (r-4-5) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- coordinate[pos=.25] (r-3-4) (C3);
  \path [line] (r-3-4) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- coordinate[pos=.25] (r-2-3) (C2);
  \path [line] (r-2-3) --++ (1cm, 0cm) |- (C1);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Elegant solution with `pos=.25`: +1

Answer (score 13):

A few notes before hand:

1. The `arrows` (and the `arrows.spaced`) library is deprecated since version 3.0 of TikZ/PGF. It still works, but the new `arrows.meta` library offers so much more options and reliability.
2. The `? of=?` syntax is deprecated (and really shouldn't be used anymore), see also [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386/16595). Use the `positioning` library and the `below=? of ?` syntax. The behavior of the old keys can be generated with the `on grid` options.
3. I have used the `chains` library (which relieves us from using repeatable using `\node` and `below=of`. [Some may say](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/71/#8a1a) that even `chains` is "outdated" and the new `graphs` library is much more powerful (some would be correct). I added an example for the `graphs` library. Adding the edge paths inside the `\graph` options and/or as part of the `graphs` library is left to the reader.

[Indeed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238202/connecting-from-in-the-middle-of-line#comment565213_238202), it seems my udlr family seems to help here.
You will need the files

- [`tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex) and
- [`tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex)

in your texmf tree or somewhere else where LaTeX can find them (in the same folder as your main `.tex` file for instance).

Amongst others it allows you to use the `r-rl` path operator which means to draw an orthogonal connection between to coordinates in which you start from the first and go to the `r`ight then up- or downwards and then `l`eft to the target coordinate (or node).
You can write `r-rl[distance=?]` to change the distance between nodes/coordinates and the vertical part of the path (default: 0.5cm). The option `from center` adds the distance from the center of nodes (instead of their borders).

In your example I add an additional (auxiliary) name for the last node and add with the `coordinate (@)` a coordinate on the connection which allows me to use the same `\path` specification repeatedly. This `@` coordinate (with an default `pos=.5`) is placed at middle of the vertical part of the `r-rl` connection.

All these options and how they effect the placement of nodes/coordinates along the path are explained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595) to [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz).

---

If you still want to use `|-`, I'd advise you to use a `to path` as defined in:

```
rl/.style={
  near start,
  to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0) |- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
rl/.default=.5
```

and then you can easily do

```
\foreach \i in {4,...,1}
  \path (@.east) edge[line, rl] coordinate (@) (ch-\i);
```

Note that you have to `.east` otherwise the first connection is much closer to the `4` and `5` nodes as the distance in `++(X, Y)` is calculates from the center of nodes. (A coordinate is only a point so the `.east` anchor is just the same as the coordinate without an anchor.)

The `rl` style also sets `near start` (which is a short-cut for `pos=.25`) so that it automatically uses a point halfway on the vertical part.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho, chains, graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shorten >= 1pt, node distance=.4cm, semithick,
  line/.style = {draw=black, thick},
  team/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm},
]
\begin{scope}[start chain=ch going below]
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \node [on chain, team] {\small \i};
\end{scope}
\path (ch-end) [late options={alias=@}];
\foreach \i in {4,...,1}
  \path[line] (@) r-rl coordinate (@) (ch-\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shorten >= 1pt, semithick,
  line/.style = {draw=black, thick},
  team/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm}
]
\graph[name=C, branch down sep=.4cm, typeset=\small\tikzgraphnodetext, nodes=team]
  {\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{\i}};
\path (C 5) [late options={alias=@}];
\foreach \i in {4,...,1}
  \path[line] (@) r-rl coordinate (@) (C \i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution. How someone, who don't know for given links for tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex and tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex, find them? Can I expected that they will be mentioned in next (cvs) version of TikZ manual?

Comment: @Zarko Check my user-page. There will always be a link to the library files and the answers which spawned the idea for udlr as well as `-|-`/`|-|` (where the links are posted a second/third time). Tantau hasn't added these path operators into the recent version of TikZ (and maybe he hasn't seen it before or wasn't convinced), I don't believe they will be added in the future unless people ask him to do so. Nearly all functionality could be replicated with `to path` except—to my knowledge—the timer function (which translates the `pos` value in a coordinate).

Answer (score 6):

For whom it may interest, here is a MetaPost solution, with the help of the `boxes` package.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes; input mpcolornames;
    beginfig(1); 
      % circular boxes: definitions
      boxjoin(a.s - b.n = (0, .5cm)); circmargin := 3mm;
      for i = 1 upto 5:
        circleit.c[i]("\sffamily" & decimal i);
      endfor
      % circular boxes: drawings
      for i = 1 upto 5:
        fill bpath c[i] withcolor .25[white,blue];
        draw bpath c[i] withcolor blue;
        drawunboxed(c[i]);
      endfor
      % connexions defined and drawn iteratively
      h := .75cm; o := h;
      pair A, B, C, D; A = c4.e ; B = A + (h, 0); C = D + (h, 0); D = c5.e;
      draw A + (pt, 0) -- B -- C -- D;
      for i = 3 downto 1:
        h := h + o;
        D := .5[B, C]; A := c[i].e; B := A + (h, 0); C := D + (o, 0);
        draw A + (pt, 0) -- B -- C -- D;
      endfor 
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be processed with LuaLaTeX. Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short hacky solution using `foreach`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[team/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, minimum size=8mm}]
    \foreach[count=\i, remember=\k as \j (initially 0), evaluate={\k=.5*(\i+\j)}] \l in {4,...,1}
      \draw (\i-1,\j) -- ++(1,0) |- (0,\i) node[team]{\l};
    \node[team] {5}; % the final touch
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]