# When using custom path style in a tikz graph the quotes label isn't printed

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I can put labels onto normal edges fine, but when the edge has a style applied to it, the label is no longer applied.

Any idea what is going on/how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz[hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}}]
\graph[grow down sep, branch right = 4em] {
A ->["this prints"] B ->{C,D};
A ->[hv path,"this doesn't"] D;
}; 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}]` work?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yep, that's the ticket! (I was just playing around with the same idea here.) Would you like to answer?

Comment: Cool, that seems to work, though the labels are in the wrong place, I'm sure I can move them. Any idea why that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes are actually applied, however they do not show up as the `to path` declaration in `hv path` misses the `\tikztonodes` macro which will then expand to the nodes that has been collected at some point by the `quotes` library.

The full and correct definition of `hv path` is

```
hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
```

The nodes are by default placed at `pos = .5` (= `midway`) along the path. At normal line-tos this is at the actual middle of the line. With the orthogonal paths `-|` and `|-` this is at the corner. The position `pos = .75` (= `near end`) is at the midway point of the second part. (See also [Node on a jointed TikZ path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97399/node-on-a-jointed-tikz-path/97404#97404).)

The key `swap` (or its short-cut `'`) can be used to place a node along a path at the other side. (The graph uses internally the `auto` option that defaults to `auto=left`. The `swap` key swaps this to `auto=right` and vice versa.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz[hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}]
  \graph[grow down sep, branch right = 4em] {
    A ->["this prints", '] B ->{C,D};
    A ->[hv path,"this doesn't" near end] D;
  }; 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]